# Best Lightweight JS Framework for Low Speed Internet Region?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks

We are trying to develop a web-based e-commerce system targeting rural area, which has only 3G~ internet. Worried that modern JS framework is too heavy for them.

Would Vue be a good choice? If not is there any suggestion?

We'd tried using Vue, but worried that it's not the best choice.

Comment: This violates SO guideline. Anyways, Instead of worrying about framework i think it's better to think about caching for offline usage. You can develop a PWA that caches all static files and only relies on internet for dynamic data. Also give consideration to edge locations.

Comment: This is bike shedding. The footprint of a framework itself is ~100 kb *ungzipped*, the footprints of custom components may vary but it's still insignificant when compared to stylesheets and third-party libs, especially since the comps shouldn't be loaded all at once. In your case UX will totally depend on how you build the app and the expertise with the framework and SPA/PWA in general, not on the choice of framework. Vue is ok.

Answer (score 1):

A framework with a small footprint (few kb:s) is Preact.

https://preactjs.com

It is very similar to React but much smaller in kilobytes.

Comment: Another alternative is petite-vue and it's very similiar to Vue.